# CKEditor Not Showing when I publish my site

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I included all of the files and everything when I published my site to our development environment. The sample index.html file works, but CKEditor shows up like this when I load the page that I am trying to call it on:
[CKEditor issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyTXU.jpg)

Here is the code that I have on the backend and it worked on my personal computer when debugging it, just not when I published it to our development/test environment.

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtDescription" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server"  Height="250px" Width="500px"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is? Our site is using ASP/C#.

Comment: Did you updated web.config file as well? there is one tag needs to be add in web.config. Please see here.http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Samples. Hope this will help.

Comment: I did that and it still does not work.

Comment: Please check the path of ckeditor folder as you have mentioned "/BasePath="/ckeditor/", is it the same directory structure on server?

Comment: Yes, the directory structure on both the server and client side is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Base path needed to be
 `"/BasePath="~/ckeditor/"`
on the server for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If You check the Host Site. The CKEditor is not copied there. Also, Check into Your Visual Studio IDE "**Solution Explorer**" Click on the Icon: "Show All Files" ->
[image: Show All Files]

You should have the CKEditor there, but not on Server. It is not automatically deployed depending your Folder Structure.